# Can we combine the "javac" and "java" commands

Tags: java, command-line, groovy

The Groovy command-line command "groovy" appears to compile a Groovy source file (.groovy) to a .class file and then run it (if it's a script).

Is there a good reason why there is no equivalent command to both compile and run a .java file?*

Why do we need to do two steps?

```
javac XXX.java
java XXX
```

why not just

```
java XXX
```

?

*perhaps I am gravely mistaken and there is such a thing

Comment: obviously, it's nice to have the ability to compile and run in separate steps, but there should be a third command to do both in one for you, right?

Comment: It's extremely rare to have to compile just one Java file. Usually, a project has hundreds if not thousands of classes. It's also quite rare to only need javac to build the project. And usually, developers work inside an IDE that builds everything for them.

Comment: @JBNizet That's more of a limitation in the tooling, IMOHO. I can "just run" Scala code (albeit generally not done for an entire compilation unit).

Comment: IMO you should be able to run a single .java file with a single command.

Comment: @AlexMills But that's not how the *standard* tooling works - wanting something doesn't make it so :) That being said, I have had very little experience with non-Sun/Oracle Java environments so .. might be possible somewhere.

Comment: maybe I will read about how the groovy command combines the two, if I can find that info somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it?  Yes.  It is simple to write a script that runs `javac` followed by `java`.

Is it a good idea?  Well that's up to you to decide.  But I think you would find that running `javac` followed by `java` takes *significantly* longer than just running `java`.  So unless you typically run a Java program just once, it makes sense to keep the two steps separate.

So ...

> Is there a good reason why there is no equivalent command to both compile and run a .java file?

Yes.  Because you typically *want* to compile (build) and run as separate steps ... for performance reasons.

Answer (score -1):

Groovy is a dynamic language. So there is no compile step. It's write->execute. When you develop an application with Groovy what you ship is the actual source you've written. Java is a static language. When you are developing something with Java you do write->compile->execute. Once you have developed the application what you ship is the compiled code. That's why there is a separate command 'javac', to compile the code and produce the artifacts that you would be shipping to the customer. Of course when developing it's much easier to run the java code directly. Most IDE's provide this. e.g: In eclipse you could just run a Java class which has the main method.

=================================

EDIT : for whoever downvoted :-)

I outlined the different intents of Groovy and Java. Groovy is meant to be a dynamic/scripting language. Therefore like many other such languages doesn't have the 'compile' step. Java is meant to be a static language. Therefore a 'compile' step is present where you do the static type checking.

Comment: From my limited knowledge, this is not true. .groovy files are compiled to standard .class files, then run, just like Java.

Comment: Yeah, `groovyc` exists for the purpose of compiling Groovy and it compiles to Groovy-independent `.class` files. Yes, it has a compiler API for dynamic class generation, modification and loading but so does Java since release 6.

Comment: @AlexMills yeah groovy does compile the groovy code to bytecode. Any language running on the JVM has to do that. But it's done dynamically when you run the code. I'm just differentiating Groovy/Java based on the intent of those languages. One is meant to be dynamic whilst other static. Also it does not generate .class files on the hard disk. It's all done in memory

Comment: To your edit: Sorry but Groovy is *not* meant to be a dynamic scripting language. Yes, you *can* do that with it but it is a fully fledged alternative language on the JVM with the *ability* to be used as a scripting language where needed. And as I already mentioned, nowadays you can do the exact same thing with plain Java, people just seem to gloss over the Agents, Compiler and Annotation Processing API:s because they're not as nicely prepackaged as Groovy (and other JVM alternatives) are.

Comment: @Esko groovy web site says 'groovy ... is an agile and dynamic language for the Java Virtual Machine' so i'm guessing it was meant to be a dynamic language.